# Inheritance in .NET : class inherited to another by it should be not visible outside

Tags: .net, inheritance

I've just started working with .NET Language so don't know much about it.

My Question is I have an class that have some properties (and don't want this class to be exposed to outside world) and its been inherited into another class which is exposed to outside world, how can I achieve this using .NET

For example - Here an example up to my understanding

I have a Class Library which has 2 classes

```
internal class A
{
   protected int data{get;set;}
}

public class B : A
{
  public B()
  {

 }

  public void SetDataInA(int value)
  {
     data = value;
  }
}
```

Outside Create Console Help, in console application have imported Class Library

```
class Program 
{
  public static void Main(String []args)
  {
     B obj = new B();
     obj.SetDataInA(1);

     // But in this i don't want that "A" class should not be visible & accessible in the console app

  }
}
```

Comment: You can't. You will get a compiler error : Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'A' is less accessible than class 'B'

Comment: Ya i know but i'm asking that is there any other way that i can achieve the same

Answer (score 1):

You can use interfaces and [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) to do this. You cannot do this with abstract classes because the base class and inherited class must marked with the same accessibility value. (*Note that if you only care about the class members mark the **members** with `private` or `protected` or `internal` and leave the class as `public`*).

### Example

Type `B` implements interfaces `IA`'s `Val` property using [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation). This means that property `Val` is only accessible if you cast the instance of `B` to interface `IA` and `IA` is marked as `internal` so only accessible inside the project/module where it is defined.

```
public class B : IA {
    int IA.Val {get;set;}
}

internal interface IA {
    int Val {get;set;}
}
```